# GRANT privileges on child table which specific parent

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions

I am doing a condominium database under Postgres with these three tables (among others)
The tables are listed only with the PK and the FK involved in my problem to simplify the code

```
TableName: Administrator
PK: admin_id

TableName: Condo
PK: condo_id
FK: admin_id (Connects with Administrator of this condo)

TableName: Property
PK: property_id
FK: condo_id (Connects with parent condo)
```

Now, imagine there is a administrator with admin_id = 1 and I create a SQL user for him, for example:

```
CREATE ROLE "john_smith"
LOGIN PASSWORD '123456'
VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

So now I want him to only update the Properties related to a Condo that has him as administrator (admin_id = 1)

How could I do something like

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
ON Property
WHERE "The Properties of a Condo with admin_id = 1"
TO "john_smith"
```

That's the question, thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specified, I add it on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it on Postgress and this is called [Row Security Policies](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html)

But you have not posted enough information about your DB to have a clear answer.

The idea is that you have to create specific `ROLES` that are `GROUPS` of `USERS`

In your example you created only a **user** role. You should add an *Administrators* **usergroup** and add your admin users to it.

Then you do something like

```
ALTER TABLE Property ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY Property_Administrator ON property TO Administrators
    USING (SELEcT true FROM condo WHERE condo.condo_id=property.condo_id AND  condo.admin_id= current_user);
```

Just read the doc I linked and you'll achieve it pretty simply

Comment: it's almost ok, but the problem is that the admin_id is not on Property, it is on Condo (A communitty group of properties) but I will take a look around Row Security Policies, thank you!

Comment: @jsertx I read the question too quickly indeed. I have adapted the `create policy` query accordingly. I think that it should do the trick